# Is there a way to refresh the entity value in hibernate/grails without refreshing from the database

Tags: hibernate, grails

(I'll use Groovy/Grails syntax in sample)

In hibernate when an entity is loaded, they are kept on the session cache/L1, the problem is they do not get refereshed if changed outside of the session, even if I requery them via GORM methods. That's why I use refresh().

(All of the following are done in one session.)

```
User.withNewTransaction {
  User user = User.findById(1L, [lock: true]) //select for update
  user.name='new name' 
  user.save()
}

//user entity gets updated on a different thread.

User.withNewTransaction {
  user = User.findById(1L, [lock: true]) //another select for update
  //at this point, the user entity is not yet filled in with the updated values from the different thread
  //so I'm forced to do a refresh so that the user will have the correct values
  user.refresh()
  //update user
}
```

Is there an alternative to this?

This means I have to query twice to make sure we have the correct value on the 2nd transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Simply drop the `refresh` :

```
User.withNewTransaction {
  user = User.findById(1L) //user = User.findById(1L, [lock: true]) //another select for update
  //at this point, the user entity is not yet filled in with the updated values from the different thread
  //so I'm forced to do a refresh so that the user will have the correct values
  //user.refresh()
  //update user
}
```

A better solution is to drop the transaction! since transactions are used for *batch* operations :

```
user = User.findById(1L)
```

If you wish to keep the transaction syntax, then it makes more sense to join it to other *ongoing transactions* using `withTransaction`:

```
User.withTransaction {
      user = User.findById(1L) //user = User.findById(1L, [lock: true]) //another select for update
      //at this point, the user entity is not yet filled in with the updated values from the different thread
      //so I'm forced to do a refresh so that the user will have the correct values
      //user.refresh()
      //update user
    }
```

**Summery:**

You should rarely use `refresh`, as it ignores *hibernate advantages*, unless there is a special need specified [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html)

Comment: If I remove the refresh call, the value on the user might become stale. Due to other threads possible modifying it. I have to use the transaction blocks due to a certain requirement.

Comment: We need locking so that other threads would not touch the entity that we are currently modifying. 
Regarding, mixing up with locking and direct fetching, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean skip hibernate and just use native sql? Can you please expound on it?